# i cant add Firebase to my react expo project

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, expo, npm-install

I tried cmd code " npm install firebase" but it's getting some error

C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta>expo install firebase
Installing 1 SDK 40.0.0 compatible native module using npm.

> npm install
> npm ERR! code EPERM
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules\ascli
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules.ascli-fmD4I2Bu
> npm ERR! errno -4048
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules\ascli' -> 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules.ascli-fmD4I2Bu'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules\ascli' -> 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules.ascli-fmD4I2Bu'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
> npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules\ascli',
> npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\Users\jupun\OneDrive\Documents\reactNative\Expo\insta\node_modules\.ascli-fmD4I2Bu'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-23T07_54_19_335Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 4294963248
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 4294963248
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:483:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
at Socket. (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:376:20)
at Pipe. (node:net:666:12)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:157:31)
at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:100:18)
at installAsync (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\install.ts:129:3)
at Command. (C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:346:7)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can often be fixed by an

```
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Many users to this day, seem to report this issue, including me and the solution I found for this problem is either:

- downgrading your node version to `10.16.0` and than use expo command
- installing firebase `firebase@8.2.3` with npm or yarn (but you will get warning from Expo.)

Please check out
[these answers #3066](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3066)

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Android Studio or Xcode for Mac